# permutation of the elements of a matrix with respect to sign?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, permutations

Let matrix $\mathcal A$ with a $(m\times n)$. Every element $a_{i,j}$ of the matrix is either a *positive* or *negative* integer, or *zero*.

***Question:*** *How many distinct matrices could be generated with respect to the above distinction for matrix $\mathcal A$ - please provide a general formula?*

Example: A matrix $(2 \times 1)$ with two elements has 9 distinctions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only are interested in the sign, not the size of the integer, then you have three options for each entry, so for an $m \times n$ matrix you would have $3^{(m\times n)}$ possibilities.

Comment: thanks. may be you have an idea also for this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/441452/matrix-operator-for-sign-function